# C dup2 overwrite file bug when line > 1

Tags: c, cat, dup

I have the following simple program that catenates infile to outfile

```
  char *execArgs[] = { "cat", NULL};
  int outfile = open("outfile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
  int infile = open("infile", O_RDONLY, 0);
  dup2(outfile, STDOUT_FILENO); 
  dup2(infile, STDIN_FILENO); 
  close(outfile);
  close(infile);
  execvp(execArgs[0], execArgs);
```

Now, suppose the content of infile is

```
this is infile
```

and outfile is

```
this is outfile
```

After running the program, the content of outfile has an extra "e" at the end as such

```
this is infilee
```

Also, if the outfile is instead

```
this is outfile
this is outfile
```

It becomes

```
this is infilee
this is outfile
```

What is wrong?

Comment: int outfile = open("outfile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644); this line causes the problem,  you want to only create if the outfile does not already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is the expected behavior. `cat` just writes the number of bytes it reads, so since the original `outfile` is longer, the remaining bytes contain what they contained before.

If you're asking why you get different behavior from using the shell to perform:

```
cat < infile > outfile
```

the reason is that the shell opens `outfile` (or any target of `>`) with `O_TRUNC`, which truncates the file to zero length as part of opening it. You can get the same behavior by adding `| O_TRUNC` to your `open` call's flags argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `O_TRUNC` this will truncate the file it it exists.

```
int outfile = open("outfile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have an *extra* e, it has the same e it always had at that position.

Look at the strings you're writing:

```
this is infilee
this is outfile
              ^
              +-- lines up
```

The problem is that the output is not truncated, and thus it retains all its old content. You're just overwriting it from the start.